# Proguard Android App for LVL and Fragment Compatibility Support

Tags: android, proguard, android-fragments, android-lvl, android-support-library

I'm trying to use Proguard against my app which will eventually incorporate LVL and In-app Billing. The problem I have is that Proguard keeps crashing my app on start and it's hard to figure out what's failing.

I'm using the Android V4 support compatibility library and it seems to be blowing away that library as well as some other stuff.

Does anyone has a proguard.cfg that works with a basic version of the v4 compat library for starters?

Currently I'm using the stock proguard.cfg which doesn't work.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not enough to produce a working application.. proguard will for example delete all your fragments by default, and there are some more compat. libraries it uses.

I've found the following works:

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.**
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

In theory if you simply want proguard as an obfuscator and are not ineterested in its other 'features', then

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
```

Should switch it off.  Even with that, though *test thoroughly on a real android 1.6 phone*.   I didn't and found too late proguard had made a breaking change to the binary that only manifested on 1.6...

Answer (score 8):

To have Proguard working with v4 compatibility library add this to your proguard.cfg:

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```